# Javascript: composite vs prototype design

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a small game framework in Javascript currently and have finished getting most of the libraries and lower level stuff in place, so I'm not focusing my attention on the game object system. In my previous game framework in Java, I used composition which worked extremely nicely and the fact that I exposed the entire object framework to JS inspired me to work on this project. In Java, composition worked amazingly well because you no longer had to deal with type casting, or at least very rarely, so everything could be passed through the same pipelines.

However, in Javascript since it gives you the ability to dynamically add data and methods to an object, I'm wondering if it'll be best to skip the entire composition structure, but the main question here is performance. Storing a list of objects in an array and iterating through them (and invoking their methods directly) is extremely fast and has the added benefit of easy event propagation/bubbling, where as an object that's composed via prototyping would need to be ran through a giant list of checks to see if it contained various methods/data.. I think for non realtime applications, this works fine, but not when you need to render hundred of objects 30+ times a second. I'm going to write some tests for both designs, but do any of you have any input on this?

Note: this is an html5 framework.

Comment: +1 Interesting question, especially in the context of game development.

Answer (score 2):

This question is too broad to answer well. I'll try to narrow it to two bits:

> but the main question here is performance.

For one, focus on performance after you have a problem.

> as an object that's composed via
>   prototyping would need to be ran through a giant list of checks to see
>   if it contained various methods/data.

For two, this isn't true. You could very easily add a flag method to each one of your mixins - effectively collapsing your giant list to one and only one.

For example:

```
Renderable = {
  isRenderable: true
  // render magic
}

myGameObject.extend(Renderable);
```

**update**

You also may want to consider an event oriented approach. This would allow you to trigger the `Render` event and every game object who's subscribing will simply render itself. No if statements. Something like (pseudoy):

```
RenderManager.subscribe = function(subscriber) {
    this.subscribers.push(subscriber)
}
RenderManager.render = function() {
    // loop over all subscribers and render with them
}

// when initializing, add game objects to the render system
RenderManager.subscribe(myGameObject);

// then from your main game loop
RenderManager.render();
```

Comment: lol...u said "this isn't true" but in yet, you seem to be contradicting yourself with your code (if isRenderable) so yeah, maybe you're not doing a type/instance of check, but you're still explicitly making an if statement. I prefer using subsystems that handle each type of component explicitly so that you NEVER need to do explicit checking.

Comment: Of course, you still would want to do a run time type check on the object to ensure it's an expected type however. Anyway, what I am going with is a mixture of both composite and prototype design which seems to be the most logical. For example, components can rely almost entirely on prototyping, where as game objects will simply contain a list of components that can be easily managed throughout the objects life cycle.

Comment: I'm not sure the 'lol' was necessary. By 'huge lists' I simply thought you meant that you'd have to do multiple checks per game object to see if it supported certain behavior. I've updated my answer to include an approach that doesn't include any if statements if that's your concern.

Comment: Hey Deeno, sorry if I seemed to have a tone of sarcasm in my comments before. Your update is actually pretty much the same as what I have in place now, only the render component of my game object would register itself to the render manager on initialization.